# XSLT Leave start and end tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml structure similar to this.

```
<outer>
    <inner>text</inner>
    <inner2>text2</inner2>
</outer>
```

I want it to look like this, leaving the start and end tags.

```
<outer>
    <inner></inner>
    <inner2></inner2>
</outer>
```

This is the current xsl that I am using

```
 <xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Leaving me with

```
<outer>
   </inner>
   </inner2>
</outer>
```

How would I get both the start and end tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that XSLT to give you

```
<outer>
   <inner/>
   <inner2/>
</outer>
```

Which is the correct result as it's exactly the same XML as

```
<outer>
   <inner></inner>
   <inner2></inner2>
</outer>
```

Within XSLT there's no way to control which of the two equivalent representations the final serializer will use to represent the output tree.  There may be processor-specific ways to influence it, depending what processor you're using, but generally it doesn't matter as XML tools will treat both forms the same.

Comment: That is what I was thinking just thought I would ask to make sure. Is there a way to replace the text between the tags with something else say the tag name?

Comment: @stormbard You could use a template that matches "leaf" elements (those that have no element children, i.e. `match=*[not(*)]"`) and does something like `<xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></xsl:copy>`

Comment: @stormbard or you could put a dummy comment inside the element rather than some text, for example `<xsl:copy><xsl:comment> dummy </xsl:comment></xsl:copy>`

Comment: @stormbard - You could add `<xsl:output method="html"/>` to your stylesheet. That usually preserves the start/end tags. (Might not if the element name matches an HTML element that is declared as EMPTY; like `<meta/>`. This might be processor dependent too. In saxon `<meta/>` will get converted to `<meta>` (SGML start tag w/no end tag).)

Comment: If you have a solution that does not treat <this/> the same as <this></this> ... then buy a new system